# Django and haystack with whoosh, search formatting

Tags: django, django-templates

Im trying to format my search page so that it will split my results by model_name.
The problem i've got is that my heading get repeated because its inside the for loop. Is there any way to re-write this code so that the heading is only shown once?

Thanks

```
{% for result in page.object_list %}
    {% ifequal result.model_name 'post' %}
        <h3>Videos</h3>
        <p>
            <a href="{{ result.object.get_absolute_url }}">{{ result.object.title }}</a>
        </p>
    {% else %}
        <h3>Photos</h3>
            <p>
            <a href="{{ result.object.get_absolute_url }}">{{ result.object.title }}</a>
        </p>
    {% endifequal%}              
{% empty %}
    <p>No results found.</p>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check [ifchanged tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/?from=olddocs#ifchanged).

Usual algorithm in such cases is:

1) Sort results on heading field

2) Use ifchanged tag.

Comment: Thanks ill try that later, i've updated my question with some other errors.